# Using decimals in intermediate calculations?

Tags: decimals

I'm looking at a contract that takes a uint88 and divides by the product of a uint80 and a uint104. The uint80 is the inverse of ETH/USDC (ie, it is the price of one USDC in terms of ETH)...obviously this will be something like .0005 or something. The contract has to make a call to a Chainlink oracle to get the price of ETH/USDC and then take the inverse of it.

We all know ETH only works with integers so how does it treat a decimal less than 1 in an intermediate calculation? I went into remix to try to text this and it obviously wouldn't let me save a variable with a value of 1/2000 but I also tried to sort of trick it by putting the 1/2000 into a calculation (where the result would be more than 1) to see if it would multiply and then divide, but that didn't work either.

I'm wondering how this contract is making this work.

Answer (score 0):

multiply the first number by something like 10 ** 18 and only then do the division and the rest of the calculations. And at the end divide the resulting number by 10 ** 18

So in your case
invertedPrice = 10 ** 18 / price
do all calculations using this invertedPrice and finally divide the result by 10 ** 18

Comment: I understand that's how I would set it up if I were doing it, but I'm looking at a contract that doesn't set it up that way and I'm trying to figure out how solidity knows to calculate this properly. When the contract calls Chainlink for ETH/USDC and gets the inverse of it, why doesn't it just round down to 0 since the inverse of ETH/USDC is like .005?

Comment: chainlink oracles use 8 decimals for XXX/USD pairs and 18 decimals for XXX/ETH pairs. So ETH/USD would use 8 decimals and USDC/ETH - 18 decimals. Plenty of zeroes

Comment: can you include the code of the contract, so the question would be clearer?